# GcmTaskService from other package

Tags: android, package, gcmtaskservice

Can I schedule a task for a GcmTaskService from another package? I still can start an ordinary service from other package as a wrapper. But maybe there is a way to get rid of

```
    There is no GcmTaskService component registered within this package. Have you extended GcmTaskService correctly?
```

exception.